# how to open api-umbrella web browser?

Tags: api-gateway

The api-umbrella installation is successful.

want web browser to open. but, it doesn't open

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

It's Ubuntu information for i installed.

Installation process according to https://apiumbrella.io/install/

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/nrel/api-umbrella-ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/api-umbrella.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install api-umbrella
```

and start api-umbrella

```
sudo /etc/init.d/api-umbrella start
```

and According to the api-umbrella instructions, start api-umbrella after install.
Then enter [your-api-umbrella-host/admin] and tell them to connect.

I want to know what [your-api-umbrella-host] address.
i tried localhost, localhost:80, localhost:8081, localhost:8443 and so on. but no connect.

I want to see the screen of [your-api-umbrella-host] / admin. Help me

thank..

Comment: @Melebius > 
https://apiumbrella.io/install/

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61

echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/nrel/api-umbrella-ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/api-umbrella.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install api-umbrella

you actually put the space before the port number? > 
no. I did not put a space in front.

Comment: @Melebius ok. sorry!